# Need help running a compiler with input types

Tags: c#, c++

I'm working on combining multiple files with data in them to put it into one big file. I've found the compiler we need on Github here: https://github.com/AndyTWF/sector-file-compiler however I've never worked with this before or even the programming language it is in. This would help us a ton instead of copy-pasting the data one by one as we've got over 100+ files to combine.

I understand that it needs a config.json file which I have configured however I do not know where to specify the path of that file in the CompilerCLI files(?). I also want to know how I can specify where the output files will be.

The repo with the input files that are supposed to be mentioned in the .json file is in this repo https://github.com/VATFrance/FR-Sector-File

I'm a total newbie to this type of stuff so help would be appreciated!

P.S: I have Visual Studio installed already.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding this flags in your command line to setup configuration file and output

Path to the compiler configuration JSON file :

```
--config-file [arg]
```

Where the output file for the EuroScope ESE should be generated :

```
--out-file-ese [arg]
```

Where the output file for the SCT should be generated :

```
--out-file-sct [arg]
```